# Embedding a PyQtGraph into a Tkinter GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, pyqtgraph

I have a Tkinter GUI I've been working on for some time that has a live-plotting feature currently built in matplotlib. However, I'm finding matplotlib to be too slow (it seems to build up a lag over time, as if filling up a buffer of frames of incoming data), so I'm thinking of switching my plotting to PyQtGraph. Can I put this into my Tkinter app?

Comment: You can not, pyqtgraph uses Qt as a backend, which is a library that is not compatible with tkinter.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, you cannot embed a `PyQtGraph` Object inside a tkinter application.

Comment: That's a bummer, Tkinter was starting to grow on me. Do you know any ways to empty a matplotlib frame buffer, in the hopes of reducing lag? (or should I ask a new question)

Comment: @janizer that should probably be a new question. If you have not found an answer online that is.